# iphone animation with UIScrollView scrolling on top

Tags: iphone, animation, uiscrollview

I have a UIView animation which slowly moving around an image (full screen) with various transforms.

This animation of image is like a background.

On top of the animation, I have a UIScrollView, where user can scroll content.

The problem is, if the underlying image animation is going, the scrolling in the UIScrollView is very shaking, not smooth at all.

Any one can help me with that?

Comment: two things are happening in the same ui in the same thread. One of them is bound to be jerky!

Comment: so there are no way to refine that?

Comment: i dont know for sure. I cant say use multiple threads coz UI is better not be touched from a background thread.